# Featured image is not showing in wp-admin

Tags: post-thumbnails

Featured image is not displaying on wp-admin side. I have also selected 'featured image' option from **Screen Options**. While Selecting image from media it doesn't show selected image in the metabox.
I have written the below code:

```
function twentytwelve_setup() {
  add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
  }
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'twentytwelve_setup' );
```

Comment: That code looks fine. The behaviour is unusual and it's difficult to say what may be causing it. The usual debugging path would be to disable all plugins and see if the problem is still there. Then switch them on one by one.

Comment: why do you have this inside a function?  Can't you just put add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); directly inside your functions.php?

Answer (score 2):

Have you double checked if the featured-image section is enabled under the `Screen Options` tab?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can disable/comment these plugin/code one by one by which having [remove_meta_box()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box) function.

`remove_meta_box` function is used to removes a meta box or any other element from a particular [post edit](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_Posts) screen of a given [post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types). It can be also used to remove a widget from the [dashboard screen](https://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Screen).

Once you filter this things you get the cause point. Best of luck!